How can I integrate Apache DBCP2 with Spring Boot 3.0?
I am facing the problem with Spring Boot 2.7.x to 3.x.x upgrade:
Spring Boot 3.x.x requires "TransactionManager" with"Jakarta" packages, but the latest released version of DBCP2 still contains "Javax" imports
Latest version is 2.12.0 - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-dbcp2 (even tried to see if there is any released version with "jakarta" classifier, but could not find any)
How can I use DBCP2 in Spring Boot > 3.x.x ?

If the project is shareable I can give it a try... or a skeleton of the intended setup

In Spring Boot 3, the most commonly used and supported database connection pool is HikariCP. HikariCP is the default database connection pool choice for Spring Boot because of its excellent performance and simple configuration.

@life888888 will try to switch to HikariCP then, thank you :)

ah, HikariCP does not support JTA .. and my application depends on XA transactions

The answer is NO, you cannot combine JTA provider with these JDBC Connection Pools. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40912313/what-are-the-relationships-between-jta-provider-like-atomikos-and-connection-poo)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
